# ParamQuery Data Display

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I am trying to implement ParamQuery an excel like plugin in php.I am trying to fetch the data from a php which generates json output.It is fetching properly but i want to display the datas within the div:grid_array in the specified format.Am not able to do that The fields are all coming blank.

My json output code:data.php

```
<?php
 $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','pass');
 if(!$conn){
  die('Mysql connection error '.mysql_error());
 }

 $db = mysql_select_db('pop',$conn);
 if(!$db){
  die('Database selection failed '.mysql_error());
 }

 $sql = 'SELECT *FROM items';

 $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);


 $data = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $row_data = array(
   'id' => $row['Item_id'],
   'Product' => $row['Product'],
    'Brand' => $row['Brand'],
    'Model' => $row['Model']
   );
  array_push($data, $row_data);
 }

 echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

my html file which should display the data:

```
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--PQ Grid files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pqgrid.min.css" />
    <script src="pqgrid.min.js"></script>
<!--PQ Grid Office theme-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/office/pqgrid.css" />

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var url = 'data.php';
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(index, data) {
            var obj = { width: 700, height: 400, title: "ParamQuery Grid Example",resizable:true,draggable:true };
        obj.colModel = [{ title: "Id", width: 100, dataType: "integer" },
        { title: "Product", width: 200, dataType: "string" },
        { title: "Brand", width: 150, dataType: "string" },
        { title: "Model", width: 150, dataType: "string"}];
        obj.dataModel = { data:data};
        $("#grid_array").pqGrid(obj);

    });


   });
                    });


</script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="grid_array" style="margin:100px;">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe It's too late to answer already, anyway I see that you didn't set up colModel properly... I mean, you forgot to link the columns to the `"fields"`.

i.e.:

```
{ title: "Product", width: 200, dataType: "string", dataIndx: "Product" }
```

where dataIndx is the JSON field; "title" is only the caption, but not directly the data binding... and as result what you can see is the row but blank

I have based on paramgrid demo [here](http://paramquery.com/demos/grid_json)

You can see de dataIndx fields inside colModel structure...

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for your answer! Please remove your additional question from the answer and create a separate question for it.

Comment: You can create a new question using the 'Ask Question' button.

Comment: Thank you RobAu and Tarod... I have fixed my issue, I wasn't doing an assignation correctly, right now it goes fine. I have corrected the answer and I think that is the whole solution to this question. I hope this will be useful for some people :)