# ParamQuery Jquery Grid plugin not displaying Data

Tags: jquery, binding, grid, paramquery

My requirement is I need to display a data in a grid with pagination.Its going to be readonly and no editing is necessary.I looked for lot of plugins and I finally found this ParamQuery Grid from jquery.

http://paramquery.com/demos

Now my controller is sending me a ViewModel object which has two properties in it. One is a Customer property which is of type CustomerModel and one is a PaymentSummary property which is a list. So I m populating both and sending it to the View. And in the view I m trying the below code. The result is I m getting the number of rows appropriately but the rows are all blank. Meaning, my recordset from db is returning 125 rows and I can see 125 rows in the grid but I can t see the data. Not sure what is the issue. I am assuming its with the data format. Could somebody please help me with this ? I am converting my model to json object but looks like its taking an array. So not sure if that may be the reason.

```
<html>
<head>
<!--jQuery dependencies-->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script        

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-
ui.min.js"></script>
<!--PQ Grid files-->   
<link href="~/Content/pqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />   

<script src="~/Scripts/pqgrid.min.js"></script>
<!--PQ Grid Office theme-->
<link href="~/Content/pqgrid_office_theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<title>Test</title>    

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function () {
            //var data = [[1, 'Exxon Mobil', '339,938.0', '36,130.0'],
            //[2, 'Wal-Mart Stores', '315,654.0', '11,231.0'],
    //  [3, 'Royal Dutch Shell', '306,731.0', '25,311.0'],
    //  [4, 'BP', '267,600.0', '22,341.0'],
    //  [5, 'General Motors', '192,604.0', '-10,567.0'],
    //  [6, 'Chevron', '189,481.0', '14,099.0'],        
    //  [9, 'Ford Motor', '177,210.0', '2,024.0'],
    //  [10, 'ConocoPhillips', '166,683.0', '13,529.0'],
    //  [11, 'General Electric', '157,153.0', '16,353.0'],
    //  [12, 'Total', '152,360.7', '15,250.0'],
    //  [13, 'ING Group', '138,235.3', '8,958.9'],
    //  [14, 'Citigroup', '131,045.0', '24,589.0'],
    //  [15, 'AXA', '129,839.2', '5,186.5'],
    //  [16, 'Allianz', '121,406.0', '5,442.4'],        
    //  [20, 'American Intl. Group', '108,905.0', '10,477.0']];

    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.PaymentSummaryList));

    var obj = {
        width: 700, height: 300,
        title: "Grid From Array",
        numberCell: { resizable: true, title: "#" },
        editable: false,
        flexWidth: true,
        showBottom: false,
        resizable: true
    };
    obj.colModel = [
        { title: "Payment Received", width: 100, dataType: "string" },
        { title: "Interest", width: 200, dataType: "string" },
        { title: "PaymentDue", width: 150, dataType: "string", align:    
 "right" },
        { title: "Principal", width: 150, dataType: "string", align: "right"  
  }
    ];
       obj.dataModel = { data: data };

    var $grid = $("#grid_array").pqGrid(obj);

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid_array" style="margin:100px;"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Html.Raw(value) Renders value as HTML markup instead of rendering it as HTML-encoded output. (from w3schools) 
But pqGrid requires data in json format something like [{prop1:value1, prop2:value2, prop3:value3 },{prop1:value1, prop2:value2, prop3:value3},{prop1:value1, prop2:value2, prop3:value3}]. That being the reason that it displays the correct number of rows, but since it cannot read the data, it cannot display it in the grid.

Comment: Probably changing it to 
var model = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PaymentSummaryList))');
should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the same issue than in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36616876/5208330); I answered similar question but  unfortunately I didn't get feedback about advice results. You could try to do so, because I think that it's happened the same.

It lacks of dataIndx field in your obj.colModel settings:

```
{  title: "Payment Received", width: 100, dataType: "string" dataIndx: "payment_rec" } //if payment_rec is the name of the field
```

You must bind correctly your data with your model; when data is static, it doesn't matter but when you link a dynamic source you have to.